# Creating Dynamic validation list using VBA: Object Required

Tags: vba, validation, excel

I want to create data validation via VBA for dynamic numbers of rows whereas each row is containing dynamic number of columns.
I passed the variable `out` which indicates the row number on which I want to set a data validation, `x` is the last column up to which I need to check for validation i.e. I will always start with cell(out, 2) and formula will extend up to (out,x).
I tried the following code but it's giving me object required error.
I think I am making some mistake in `Formula` and `SomeNamedRange` sections of the code.
What changes should I make in the code and where I am thinking wrong?

```
Sub DataValidation(out As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer)
Sheets("first_sheet").Select                          
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(out, 2), Cells(out, x)).Name = "SomeNamedRange"
Dim RangeToCheck As Excel.Range
Set RangeToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 10))
Dim choice
Set choice = "=SomeNamedRange"
With rngRangeToCheck.Select
    Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=choice
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Also see the attached picture (Data validation should need be added to the yellow portion).[image]

**EDIT:**

I have made some changes to code as suggested in comments but I am still getting the same error in `Set choice = "=SomeNamedRange"`

Changed Code is as follows:

```
Sub DataValidation(out As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer)
Sheets("first_sheet").Select                            
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(out, 2), Cells(out, x)).Name = "SomeNamedRange"
Dim RangeToCheck As Excel.Range
Set RangeToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(out, 2), Cells(out, x))
Dim choice As String
Set choice = "=SomeNamedRange"
'y is the column number where I want validation i.e. yellow column in picture
With RangeToCheck.Cells(out, y).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=choice
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because you're trying to use the return value of .Select as an Object.  You also don't have a variable declared for `rngRangeToCheck`, and as such it isn't set to anything.  You need to either select the Range first and use the Selection object or just use the Range directly:

```
With RangeToCheck.Validation
    'Do stuff
    '...
End With   
'Or
RangeToCheck.Select
With Selection.Validation
    'Do stuff
    '...
End With
```

The second issue is with these lines:

```
Dim choice
Set choice = "=SomeNamedRange"
```

You're implicitly declaring 'choice' as a Variant, but you're assigning a String to it using Object syntax.  It should be:

```
Dim choice As String
choice = "=SomeNamedRange"
```

Comment: I have assigned the range already here 
`Set RangeToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 10))` and also changed the `rngRangeToCheck` to `RangeToCheck` but I am still getting the error. As you said I need to select the range first so is it not the way to select range?

Comment: @DeepakUniyal - Yes. You can't use the return value of .Select for a With clause.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Now I am doing it as you told `RangeToCheck.Select
With Selection.Validation
    'Do stuff
    '...
End With` But issue is not solved yet :(

Comment: Am I doing it correct? `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(out, 2), Cells(out, x)).Name = "SomeNamedRange"`  **And** `Set RangeToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 10))` **And** `Set choice = "=SomeNamedRange"`

Comment: As you were already told, remove the `Set` from `Set choice = "=SomeNamedRange"`

Comment: @Rory Thanks . Now I have issue regarding use of `=SomeNamedRange` as it is permanently set and is changing all the validations to same as the last one. So how to change formula dynamically for different rows is still a problem for me.

Comment: Assign `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(out, 2), Cells(out, x)).Address` to the validation instead of using named ranges

Comment: @Comintern Can you please update your answer as per discussion in the comments so that I can accept it.